# R: Shiny Flexdashboard: Why won't selectInput display all options?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a super simple selectInput feature as follows in a flexdashboard running Shiny:

```
selectInput("dropletModel", "Choose model to represent infectious passengers:",
      list(`Coughing` = list("Bronchial/laryngeal/oral","Duguid","Loundon & Roberts"),
           `Speaking` = list("Bronchial/laryngeal/oral"),
           `Breathing` = list("Bronchial/laryngeal/oral"))
    )
```

But it doesn't show all the three options, instead missed out Bronchial/laryngeal/oral and the "Speaking" level all together. Any thoughts why?

[image]

Comment: i think you can supply how many you want to see using `maxOptions` so something like `maxOptions = 100` should work?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I doesn't seem to make any difference to the list. I tried just putting my choices into the default example and it still doesn't work: selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
      list(`East Coast` = list("BLO", "Duguid", "L & R"),
           `West Coast` = list("BLO"),
           `Midwest` = list("BLO"))
    )

Comment: you need to specify it in options e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710947/display-all-values-in-a-shiny-selectinput-box-1000

Comment: Thank you; I've figured it out. It's because the same name appears in each list.